# Error: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Messaging"

Tags: react-native

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Messaging":
In Podfile:
RNFBMessaging (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging`) was resolved to 18.3.0, which depends on
Firebase/Messaging (= 10.12.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/Messaging (= 10.12.0)`.

You have either:

- out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
- mistyped the name or version.
- not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Comment: try this ----> out-of-date source repos which you can update with pod repo update or with pod install --repo-update.